# Exception : (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL) when using WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, comexception

I have created a WinForms application which uses BackgroundWorker. The methods in BackgroundWorer displays messages on a RichTextBox. The _TextChanged event handler scrolls to the end of the RichTextBox.

Now the problem is that, I get an

> UnHandled COMException : 0x8001010D
>   (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)

when RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret() is called from the _TextChanged event handler.
What could be the problem? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you accessing the richtextbox directly from the backgroundworker?

Comment: Accessing controls from a different thread than the UI thread is strictly forbidden. Most controls have explicit checks and will throw an exception when it detects this situation, perhaps RichTextBox doesn't. You need to marshal the manipulation of the richtextbox to the UI thread using `Invoke` from your backgroundthread. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Yes. RichTextBox is updated from BackgroundWorker. 
Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the comments, you're accessing RichTextBox directly from the backgroundworker.

Accessing UI controls from multiple threads is strictly forbidden. Only the UI thread should access the controls.

You fix this you need to marshal the execution of the code that manipulates the UI controls (the RichTextBox in this case) onto the main UI thread, the thread that owns the RichTextBox.

You can do this in your backgroundworker code like this:

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // code that manipulates the RichTextBox here
}));
```